# Load two files with different suffix into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a directory of files:

```
dog_A_final.bed
dog_B_final.bed
bird_A_final.bed
bird_B_final.bed
cat_A_final.bed
cat_B_final.bed
```

I want to add only two files at a time to a df, based on their prefix - so `dog_A_final.bed` and `dog_B_final.bed` would go into one df.

The directory has hundreds of files, so I'd like to load them in and then automatically run a merge (with another dataset) on each one with an automated output of `prefix.csv` (e.g. `dog.csv`).

I know I can add all of these files to one dataframe using:

```
path = r'C:\\data\\'              
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.bed")) 

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t') for f in all_files)
dfall = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

I don't know if some modification of that is the way to go for two files at a time though.

Comment: I guess you will need to use `slipt('_')[0]` on the name of the files and go with a loop `for` on different prefix.

Comment: @Ben.T You have a bit of a dangerous assumption that `_` appears only within this pattern, no? It could  be `foo_bar/h_h_A_i_i.bed`, possibly.

Comment: @AmiTavory Good point, but first I say "the name of the files" and not the path, and then with what the OP gave as example, this assumption is ok. I didn't pretend give an answer, it was more my idea how to proceed :)

Comment: @Ben.T Good points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in a function:

```
def read_two(files):
    df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t') for f in files)
    return pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

You can order the names by the prefix:

```
import os 

byname = {}
for name in all_files:
    short_name = os.path.split(name)[-1]
    byname.setdefault(short_name.split('_', 1)[0], []).append(name)
```

Now `byname` would look like this:

```
{'bird': ['bird_A_final.bed', 'bird_B_final.bed'],
 'cat': ['cat_A_final.bed', 'cat_B_final.bed'],
 'dog': ['dog_A_final.bed', 'dog_B_final.bed']}
```

Now, put all dataframes in a dictionary by prefix:

```
dfs = {name: read_two(files) for name, files in byname.items()}
```

Now, you access your dataframes in the dict `dfs`:

```
{'bird': <bird_df>,
 'cat': <cat_df>,
 'dog': <dog_df>}
```

like this:

```
dogdf = dfs['dog']
```

or do your processing in a loop:

```
for name, df in dfs.items():
     merged = df.merge(animals, on=['col'])
     merged.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(name))
```

Comment: How would I access each one iteratively? For example, if I wanted to do `dogdf = dog.merge(animals, on=['col']); dogdf.to_csv('dog.csv')` followed by `birddf = bird.merge(animals, on=['col']); birddf.to_csv('bird.csv')` followed by all the others?

Comment: I tried playing around with the `setdefault(name.split('_', 1)[0], [])` because as-is it gives me the whole path in front of my file. Could you further explain what the `1` and `[0],[]` are doing? Or how I could get just `dog` from `C:\\data\\dog`?

Comment: @Liquidity You can get `dog` from `C:\\data\\dog` with `os.path.split(...)[1]`.